# How to change <i> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I'm working on a website that currently uses <i> tag with class I found on [fontawesome.com](https://fontawesome.com/). It looks like this:

```
<li id="icon" class="hvr-underline-from-left notdropdown"><span><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></span></li>
```

id="icon" is used to execute javaScript code to flip between light and dark mode. In css I declared variables that have colors that this website uses and with JavaScript I toggle those two pallettes.

CSS:

```
:root{
    --primary-color: #ffffff ;
    --secondary-color: #eeeeee;
    --tertiary-color: #192b85;
    --text-color: #000000;
}
.dark-theme{
    --primary-color: #1c1d1f;
    --secondary-color: #252b30;
    --text-color: #ffffff;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var iconFlip = document.getElementById("icon");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon").click(function()
    {
        $("body").toggleClass("dark-theme");
        
    });
});
```

I wanna change the moon icon that is provided by <i> tag to sun icon from the same webiste, when I press that and flip into dark mode.

I tried adding this:

```
  if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme"))
        {
          iconFlip.classList = "fa-solid fa-sun";
        }
```

Into my function but it doesnt work
I also tried adding id= sun  to <i> tag and adding this to javascript code:

```
if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme"))
        {
          sun.setAttribute('class', "fas fa-sun");
        }
```

EDIT:
The closest I got to working javascript was this:
I added id="sun" to <i> tag and made this javscript

```js
var iconFlip = document.getElementById("icon");
var darkmode = document.getElementById("sun");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon").click(function()
    {
        $("body").toggleClass("dark-theme");
       
        if(document.getElementById("sun").className = "fas fa-moon")
        {
            document.getElementById("sun").className = "fas fa-sun";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("sun").className = "fas fa-sun")
        {
            document.getElementById("sun").className = "fas fa-moon";
        }
        
    });
});
```

It changes icon from sun to moon while going from light mode to dark mode, but doesn't change the sun icon into moon icon while changing from Dark mode back to the light mode.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the icons which are generated by  element, add the id="iconFlip" to the  element and not

.

Assuming you have fetched the  element correctly, in the variable `iconFlip`,

1. First remove the existing classes by using remove()

```js
iconFlip.classList.remove("fa-moon")
```

2. Then add the sun class to classist

```js
iconFlip.classList.add("fa-moon")
```

Effectively, try writing this code:

1. Remove the id from `li` and add it to `i` tag (since the current code will change classList on `li` and not `i`).

```html
<li class="hvr-underline-from-left notdropdown"><span><i id="iconFlip" class="fas fa-moon"></i></span></li>
```

2. I don't know the whole JS code you are writing but these 2 snippets might help

```js
// fetch the <i> element
var iconFlip = document.getElementById("iconFlip")

// then when the button is clicked
    $("#icon").click(function()
    {
        $("body").toggleClass("dark-theme");
        // remove the current moon class so that no icon is displayed
        iconFlip.classList.remove("fa-moon");
        // not add fa-sun (or whatever class it shows on fontawsome), to show sun icon
        iconFlip.classList.add("fa-sun")
    });
```

Comment: Could you please re-phrase it somehow differently? I am quite new to this

Comment: @wladzikxx You are fetching the incorrect element. the id you are fetching is owned by li element not the i. You also need to use classList.remove to remove the old classes and add the new ones with classList.add

Comment: I've tried your solution, sadly it doesn't work, literally nothing changes. Additionally, placing ID in <i> tag makes it so I have to precisely click on the icon to change to dark mode, instead of clicking on the area around it.